# Jquery plugin using deferred object not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function ( $ ){            
    $.fn.customAlert = function(callback ){
        buttonClicked().then(function(){
            if (typeof callback == 'function'){
                callback.call(this);
            }
        }, function(){
            alert("didn't work");
        }).always(function(){               
            });
    };    
}( jQuery ));
```

I'm trying to create a custom prompt and this is what I have so far. The buttons show up and I call `$.customAlert(...);` in another part of my javascript but the buttons don't generate any response.

`Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'customAlert'`

Comment: Did you look at the error console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating `customAlert` in `$.fn`. That is used for adding methods to *jQuery selections*. This is why calling `$.customAlert(...);` will not work. If you want to be able to invoke `customAlert` in this way, you should assign it to `$`, not `$.fn`. Otherwise, you would have to invoke it with `$('some selector').customAlert`.

Comment: jeez, so simple. Thanks. I am; however, getting an error from the console telling me that `buttonClicked is not defined`.

Comment: You're defining `buttonClicked` inside of your `ready` handler, so it's not visible to that block of code. You'll have to move it outside of the ready handler, or create `$.customAlert` inside that same handler.

Comment: Awesome, that did it. I think I just got excited about jquery. :)